# Firebase query by child's child key

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this structure in my Firebase database [image: structure]

How I can get "ch1" knowing one of uids? ("uid1"/"uid2")
I tried this:
`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("messages").orderByChild("users").startAt("users",partnerId)`, but it gave me all chats.

Comment: Do you want to simply access a known chapter? If so: attach your listener to `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages/ch1")`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen , no, I want to find this "ch1". There can be any of "ch$" containing some "uid$"

Comment: Ah.. that's a categorization problem. If you want to be able to get all chapter for a specific user, you should model precisely that: keep a list of the chapters for each user. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value